# Make div slide up when another div is hovered on

Tags: html, css

I have a block called `case-card` which consists of a child div called `case-card__wrapper` that houses text.

On `case-card` hover, I want the `case-card__wrapper` to move up slightly. Not in one action, but as transition.

I feel like I have the general idea, but unsure on how to get the transition to work? At the moment, it just phases from one spot to another:

```css
.case-card {
    height: 560px;
    width:600px;
    color: #ededed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #333; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.case-card__wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    transition: 0.5s;
    /*top: 0; Don't want to add this because I want the text to be centered in the div and rather not define a number since the div heights may vary  */
}
.case-card__title{
  font-size: 16px;
}
.case-card:hover .case-card__wrapper {
  top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="case-card__wrapper">
    <h4 class="case-card__title">Title</h4>
    <p class="case-card__subtitle">Subtitle</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to do this just via CSS. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot set initial value simply use transfrom. You can also remove `position:absolute`

```css
.case-card {
    height: 560px;
    width:600px;
    color: #ededed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    transform: translateY(20px);
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #333; 
    overflow: hidden;
}
.case-card__wrapper{
    transition: 0.5s;
 }
.case-card__title{
  font-size: 16px;
}
.case-card:hover .case-card__wrapper {
  transform:translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="case-card">
  <div class="case-card__wrapper">
    <h4 class="case-card__title">Title</h4>
    <p class="case-card__subtitle">Subtitle</p>
  </div>
</div>
```